# Using the edit - merge - commit workflow in TFS Source Control

Tags: tfs

Ive been using sourcegear vault and subversion/visual svn for quite a while now and am a big fan of the CVS disconnected style "Edit -> Merge -> Commit" way of using source control.

Since we moved to TFS 2010 i have been reintroduced to the horrid "checkout -> edit -> checkin" sourcesafe style way of working.  Meaning only one user can work on a file at any time.

I cant find anything that suggests this can be changed.

Is it possible?

Comment: Good management, in my opinion.  We've been using TFS in an enterprise setting for over a year now with millions of lines of code managed, and we haven't had any problems with it.  I like SVN, but the prejudice against TFS by some SO users is mind-boggling.

Comment: i use SVN for personal work, not at the company.  We have migrated from vault to TFS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Checkouts in TFS aren't generally exclusive. By default, multiple users can checkout a single file. Exceptions are binary file types like JPGs, PNGs, etc. which are checked out exclusively by default.

Once you're ready to commit your changes, you can use the Pending Changes tool window to check for conflicts and merge if necessary.

Comment: Clearly i had wrongly assumed it was locking the files, as they come up with a user against them when others check them out. Thanks.